# How to refer to TableLayout cells in code

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout defined in my xml with three columns and four rows plus a heading row.
Each column contains a TextView.

```
    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/inventory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Item"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Quantity"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Units"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell10"
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell11"
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell12"
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell20"
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell21"
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell22"
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell30"
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell31"
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell32"
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell40"
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell41"
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inventorycell42"
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Is there any way of referring to the TextViews in code, without having to id them individually. I was thinking there might be come way of getting row/col views from the tableview.

-Frink

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ViewGroup#getChildAt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) and [`ViewGroup#getChildCount`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount()). `getChildAt` on your root `TableLayout` will allow you to get the `TableRow`s and subsequently calling it on the `TableRow`s will allow you to access the `TextView`s.

Answer (score 2):

I liked marmor's way of solving this. I modified it somewhat for my own project. I use it to filter out all the textviews of a tablelayout regardless of the number of columns or rows. Here is the code:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = getView().findViewById(R.id.tableStats);
ArrayList<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < tableLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
    TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < tableRow.getChildCount(); j++){
        View tempView = tableRow.getChildAt(j);
        if(tempView instanceof TextView){
            textViews.add((TextView) tempView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the same number of columns for each row, 
this simple method should do the trick:

```
private View getCellAtPos(TableLayout table, int pos) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(pos / NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS);
    return row.getChildAt(pos % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS);
}
```